# Formal proof of $\det(I + tA) = \prod\limits_{i=1}^n (1 + t\lambda_i)$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

I'm looking for a formal proof for:
$$\det(I + tA) = \prod\limits_{i=1}^n (1 + t\lambda_i).$$
I'm very new to matrix theory therefore please forgive me if you find this elementary. Your help in this matter is appreciated.

Thanks,

Edit:
$A$ is a symmetric $n\times n$ matrix and $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: You don't need to apologize for asking questions. However you should make your questions are clearly as possible. What are $\lambda _i$? The eigenvalues for $A$?

Comment: Is $A$ just any matrix?

Comment: Yes, A is a symmetric matrix and $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of A.

Comment: @Ocelotx10 Do you know about [Schur decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition)?

Comment: @GitGud Not yet.

Comment: @Ocelotx10 Do you know that any symmetric matrix is diagonalizable?

Comment: If $A$ is symmetric, then diagonalize it and the result follows readily. But this is true for any square complex matrix, since it is similar to a triangular matrix.

Comment: @GitGud I'm vaguely familiar with that theorem. I learned that in undergrad which was four years ago and I haven't used matrix theory since then.

Comment: @Ocelotx10 The thing is in order for us to answer your question we need to know what you know or what you can use. If you can use Schur, then Julien as provided an answer below. If you can't use Schur, but you can use the fact that any symmetric matrix is diagonalizable, then someone will post an answer using that fact (if no one else, it will be me). If you know about Jordan Normal Form, Berci has provided an answer below. If you can't use any of this stuff, then the answer will be too complicated, in my opinion.

Comment: @Ocelotx10 Consider accepting one of the answers below if any of them satisfies you.

Comment: @GitGud Fair enough and I understand your concern. I have seen the answers posted below and I'm willing to learn Schur decomposition so I can fully understand Julien's answer.

Answer (score 5):

This is true for every complex square matrix.
It does not need to be symmetric.

Since $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, there exists $P$ invertible such that $P^{-1}AP$ is upper triangular with diagonal $(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$ (the [Schur decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition)).

Now $P^{-1}(I+tA)P$ is upper triangular with diagonal $(1+t\lambda_1,\ldots,1+t\lambda_n)$.

So the formula follows (recall that $\det(BC)=\det(CB)$).

Note: the more I think about your question, the more I think EuYu'S answer is the right one. After all, the eigenvalues are the roots of the characteristic polynomial $p_A(\lambda)=\det(\lambda A-I)$ by definition. So your identity is actually essentially trivial. It is clearly true for $t=0$. Then factor out $t^n$ when $t\neq 0$, and it boils down to $p_A(-1/t)=\prod(-1/t-\lambda_i)$, which is true by definition of the eigenvalues (when $p_A$ splits).

Answer (score 3):

Over the complex numbers, each matrix $A$ is *equivalent* to a matrix $M$ in a [Jordan normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form), which is an almost diagonal matrix and the diagonal elements are just the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ of $A$. Being equivalent means that there is an invertible matrix $B$ (its columns contain the coordinates of the corresponding eigenvectors) such that
$$A=BMB^{-1}$$
Then $\det A=1/\det B\cdot\det M\cdot \det B=\det M=\prod_i(\lambda_i)$.

Now use that $I+tA=B(I+tM)B^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It's very clear now.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using the term symmetric, I am going to assume that the matrix in question is real. There is no real need to invoke triangularizability or any machinery. We'll simply work with basic determinant properties.

This holds generally for any real matrix with $n$ real eigenvalues, a symmetric matrix is simply a matrix which happens to satisfy this criteria.

Suppose that $A$ is $n\times n$ and let $p(t) = \det(tI - A)$ denote the characteristic polynomial of $A$. By assumption, $p(t)$ splits as
$$p(t) = \prod_{i=1}^n(t - \lambda_i)$$
We can manipulate the determinant as
$$\det(tI-A) = t^n\det\left(I-\frac{1}{t}A\right)$$
Now letting $s = \frac{1}{t}$, notice that
$$\det(I - sA) = s^{n}p(s^{-1})=s^n\prod_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{s} - \lambda_i\right)$$
which upon splitting the $s^n$ term over the terms of the product, becomes
$$\det(I - sA)=\prod_{i=1}^n\left(1 - s\lambda_i\right)$$

Comment: Yes, I think that's actually the appropriate answer to the question. And this works as soon as the characteristic polynomial splits. +1